# Heap Buffer Overflow occurs randomly....... for a simple code?(I'm new to C++)

Tags: c++

ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000114 at pc 0x000000406d27 bp 0x7ffc88f07560 sp 0x7ffc88f07558
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000114 thread T0

LeetCode No.1
I get this when I give this code

The code below works for some other inputs, but for [3,2,4]\n6, it shows the above error.

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int first = 0,last = nums.size() - 1;
        vector<int> ref = nums;
        while(first < last){
            if(ref[first]+ref[last] > target) last--;
            else if(ref[first]+ref[last] < target) first++;
            else break;
        }
        vector<int> result;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            if(ref[first]==nums[i]) result.push_back(i);
            else if(ref[last]==nums[i]) result.push_back(i);
        }
        if(result[0] > result[1])
            swap(result[0],result[1]);
        return result;
}
```

The expected output is [1,2], indexes of values in the array adding up to the value 6.

Comment: How do you call this functions? Can you please create a [mcve] to show us? What is your input? Where is the crash if you try to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? What are the values of all involved variables when the crash happens? And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: How about starting by asserting that `first` and `last`, `i`, `0`, and `1` are in range before any access of `ref` or `result`.

Comment: The way you have this written, `ref` is not a reference, it is a copy.
Also you're not changing `nums` or `ref`, so you can just pass `nums` as `const std::vector<int>& nums` and use it for both.

Comment: Since you're using `vector`, you can simply use `vector.at(i)` in place of `vector[i]`. `vector::at` does bounds checking and will throw an exception if you access the vector out of bounds. This combined with your debugger can help you catch indexing errors easily.

Comment: Possibly garbage vector passed into twoSum?  Would have to see the rest of the code to tell for sure.  Also, no reason not to use `const vector<int>& nums`.

Comment: I was wrong. I did not see the problem.

Comment: I mean, this compiles and runs fine with input of `{3,2,4}, 6` other than the standard signed/unsigned mismatch warning when comparing `int i` (signed) to `nums.size()` (unsigned), which isn't going to cause this error, and also the fact that it only returns `{1}` in `result`, which also wouldn't cause this error.

Comment: I must correct myself, that only worked in Release, where the entire function was optimized away. `if(result[0] > result[1])` will throw an error on an input of `{3,2,4}, 6` as your algorithm will only find index 1, and thus `result` will only have one value. Make sure when accessing a container that the index you are accessing exists.

Comment: Thanks @Tzalumen!!

Comment: Glad my answer was helpful.  You are on your way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this while loop.

```
while(first < last){
    if(ref[first]+ref[last] > target) last--;
    else if(ref[first]+ref[last] < target) first++;
    else break;
}
```

It seems that the intent was to break and exit when the sum is exactly equal to the target number.  However, it is not guaranteed that this will become true.  You can also exit the loop when the while condition fails, which happens whenever you reach first == last without yet finding any exact match.  That actually happens in the particular case you mention.  Follow the logic through and you will find this yourself.  The search process misses the desired answer.  The logic will not find [1,2].  It will first consider [0,2] and when that fails as too big, it will permanently decrement last and never again consider any combination that involves position 2.

(Likewise, if it fails for being too small it would increment the first position and never again consider combinations with the first value.  So there are other failure cases that would happen similarly with that scenario.)

Since you exit without finding the matching combination and first == last, only one number will be pushed into the results.  Therefore, when you just assume there are two numbers (false), things blow up as you try to reference the second result number.

**General Observation:**

You need to plan for the case where no exact match is found and code with that possibility in mind.  In that case, what would a correct return result look like to signify no solution was found?

Plus, you could think about how the algorithm could be better at not missing a solution when it is actually present.  However, that doesn't change the first requirement.  If the target cannot be matched by any sum, you need to be ready for that possibility.

**Side Notes:**

Rather than repeat the sum of two in if statements, when the sum isn't changing I would suggest that you could create and use an auto local variable once that is

```
auto sum(ref[first]+ref[last]);
```

If you want to ensure that argument vector nums is not changed, and communicate that clearly to anyone looking at the declaration of the function, a better choice would be the pass it as a const reference, e.g.

```
(const vector<int>& nums, ...)
```

Why does the code create a local copy called ref of the argument vector nums?  What is the point of making the effort to make the copy?

Regarding...

```
last = nums.size() - 1
```

...notice that if the vector passed in is empty, the value of last goes negative.  That might not cause a problem for some code, but it has a dangerous smell in that it looks like code that is just assuming that the vector passed in would never be empty.  Practice defensive coding that can be seen to guard against the possibility of unusual input values.

p.s. Part of what saves that last initialization from being broken is the use of int.  Since size() returns size_t (unsigned), a common problem is to handle it as unsigned size_t.  Then instead of going negative, the result wraps around to the maximum value and the looping may try to work with that as if that was a valid position in the vector.  It's hazardous to get into habits that invite those kinds of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that loop, solved that issue. Also thanks for the side notes.